# How to compare attributes of two files on Linux ext4

Tags: linux, files, backup, stat, file-comparison

cmp(1) will of course tell me if the contents of two files are identical, but in order to test restoring from backups I also wanted to compare the relevant (!) file attributes.

So if I did something simple like

```
mv foo.bar foo.bar.save
deja-dup --restore foo.bar # or some other backup tool
```

how do I compare the attributes of foo.bar and foo.bar.save and test for sufficient equality in a shell script (or similar). I can do

```
stat foo.bar{,.save}
```

and manually inspect the output remembering to ignore inode, atime, and ctime (as well as link count, for some reason?), but this is error prone. Is there a cmp-with-attributes tool somewhere which include SELinux and other attributes? Must work on Fedora and ext4 file systems; ideally on "all" systems. Do I need to hack something up in perl?

(No point having backups if you don't test that they work right.)

Comment: `stat` has two options, `-c` or `--format`, and `--printf`, that you can use to make it print the data you are interested in, in the format you want, so you can later compare it with `diff` or another tool.

Answer (score 7):

```
getallattr() {
  [ -L "$1" ] || lsattr -d -- "$1" | sed 's/ .*//;q'
  getfattr -hdm- -- "$1" | tail -n +2 | sort
  stat -c '%u %g %a %s %x %y' -- "$1"
}
```

To retrieve all the attributes (at least those that can easily be restored). It assumes the GNU implementation of `stat` or compatible, not the `stat` builtin of zsh. You could also include some form of digest/checksum of the contents (like with sha1sum/b2sum...) in there.

And then do

```
diff <(getallattr file1) <(getallattr file2)
```

(ksh, zsh, bash syntax).

Comment: "getfattr -dm -" already takes care of ACLs, so no need for an extra command.