# Why doesn't `getfattr -d` show anything?

Tags: linux, ntfs, xattr

The successful command from which I started:

`getfattr -n system.ntfs_times   /media/hdd/oldfolder/`

output

```
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/hdd/oldfolder/
system.ntfs_times=irrelevant
```

but if i try

`getfattr -d   /media/hdd/oldfolder/`   or `getfattr -d  -e text /media/hdd/oldfolder/` or `hex`  or `base64` as values of param `-e` i get nothing.

Why is that? I thought `-d` dump ALL attributes not NO attributes :)

Comment: I too tried and did not manage to get various options to work for me until I found and tried this:`getfattr -d -m ".*" <filename>` . Source: https://superuser.com/questions/858210/can-you-show-list-all-extended-attributes-and-how

Comment: Related: [ntfs-3g: setfattr succeeds but getfattr shows no change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180019/143394)

Answer (score 6):

To truly report all attributes you can use the argument `-dm-`, which represents the arguments `-d` and `-m -`.

For example I launched Chromium, I went to https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=86198, that action started to download a file and I named it "my_downloaded_file".

Then I executed `getfattr -m- my_downloaded_file` and it showed:

```
# file: my_downloaded_file
user.xdg.origin.url
```

although more information was shown executing `getfattr -dm- my_downloaded_file`:

```
# file: my_downloaded_file
user.xdg.origin.url="https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=86198"
```

References:

- man getfattr (e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr )
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46587
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50781
- https://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/linux_commands.html
- https://kign.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/mystery-of-plus.html

Answer (score 1):

The man page of getfattr command is not clear on this, but to really see all output, use the following switch:

```
getfattr -m - -- "$your_path_or_file_name"
```

From man page:

```
-m pattern, --match=pattern
           Only include attributes with names matching the regular expression pattern.  The default value for pattern
           is "^user\\.", which includes all the attributes in the user namespace.  Specify  "-"  for  including  all
           attributes.  Refer to attr(5) for a more detailed discussion of namespaces.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `ntfs-3g` linux driver. That driver creates some virtual xattrs, of which `system.ntfs_times` is one. When [listing xattrs](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blob/875a1d4e90874457151466870fe2c70a2bedfd98/src/ntfs-3g_common.c#L690), the driver does not list these virtual xattrs, but I don't see a reason why it couldn't. Using the [xattr mapping feature](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/Using-Extended-Attributes), you can get the xattrs in the system namespace to be mapped into the user namespace and they will then be listed. A list of these virtual xattrs can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/Using-Extended-Attributes) and the [source](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blob/a4a837025b6ac2b0c44c93e34e22535fe9e95b27/libntfs-3g/xattrs.c#L84).